# Loop will not increment past 8?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, memory-management

I have a loop that involves a dynamically allocated array in C. For some reason it crashes after `flag` increments 7 times. This wasn't happening before I was reallocating the size of the array. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) 
{

    if (audio_samples[i] > threshold  && run) 
    {

        *event_flags = (int*)realloc(*event_flags, sizeof(int)*(flag+1)); // reallocate the size of the array
        *event_flags[flag] = i;
        // printf("FLAG CREATED! %i\n ", i);
        printf("EVENT FLAG %i  %i\n",flag, *event_flags[flag] );
        if (flag >5) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }

        flag++;
        run = false;
    }
```

Any ideas? Please keep in mind that the size of the array is indeed the same value as length. Here is an example of my errors:
[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

FILE ONE:

```
   int *event_positions = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int)); // let us start with 1 and then add more within the method. This should continue until we have all the flags we want.  
   int number_of_flags = event_extractor(vocal_data, size, event_positions);
```

FILE TWO:

```
 float g_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = 2.3; // THIS INCREASES THE THRESHOLD VALUE.


 int event_extractor (int *audio_samples, unsigned int size_of_audio ,int *event_flags)
 {

int length = (int)size_of_audio;


// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
// RECTIFY VALUES (MAKE ABSOLUTE) (MAKE ALL POSITIVE)
int *rectified_audio = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int)); // I took this line from wave header reader. The number is the number of samples of the hip hop track.
make_values_absolute(audio_samples, length, rectified_audio);


   // If I convert to signed ints here would the method run more efficiently?   

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
// LOW PASS FILTER
int *lopass_samples = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int)); // I took this line from wave header reader. The number is the number of samples of the hip hop track.
lopass(rectified_audio, length,0.5, lopass_samples);



int number_of_flags = apply_threshold (lopass_samples, length, &event_flags);


printf("\n\n\n NUMBER OF EVENTS AAAA  --- %d\n", number_of_flags);

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_flags; i++) {
    printf("FLAG %i  -- %d \n", i, event_flags[i]);
}



return number_of_flags;
 }


 int apply_threshold (int *audio_samples, unsigned int size_of_audio, int **event_flags)
  {


int flag = 0; // this will be the number of flags that I have 
bool run = true; // this will make sure that a minimum amount of time passes before I grab another flag. It's a guard.
int counter = 0; // this is the counter for the above guard. 





printf("\n\nCURRENT MINIMUM TIME:  20100 SAMPLES \n\n");

// event_flags[0] = 1; // this first one is a dud. within the loop we will automatically start adding flags


int threshold = calculate_threshold_value(audio_samples, size_of_audio);

printf("\n\n this is the threshold %d \n\n", threshold);

int length = (int)size_of_audio;

printf("LENGTH OF VOCAL AUDIO %d \n", length  );  


for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) 
{

    if (audio_samples[i] > threshold  && run) 
    {

        // ** is this realloc working ?
        // event_flags = (int*)realloc(event_flags, sizeof(int) * (flag+1));
        *event_flags = (int*)realloc(*event_flags, sizeof(int)*(flag+1)); // reallocate the size of the array
        *event_flags[flag] = i;
        // printf("FLAG CREATED! %i\n ", i);
        printf("EVENT FLAG %i  %i\n",flag, *event_flags[flag] );
        if (flag >5) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }

        flag++;
        run = false;




    }   

    if (!run) {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 20100) { // hardcode minimum size for now. 
            counter = 0;
            run=true;
        }
    }

}

printf("\n\n\n NUMBER OF EVENTS --- %d\n", flag);

for (int i = 0; i < flag; i++) {
    printf("FLAG %i  -- %d\n", i, *event_flags[i]);
}



printf("\nFIVE samples before and after my second flag: \n 0 should indicate a reach in the threshold\n");

for (int i = 0; i <10 ; i++) {
    printf("VOCAL SAMPLE %i  %i \n", i-5,audio_samples[*event_flags[1]+i-5] );
}


return flag;
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the code location where you are `malloc`ing the array?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `event_flags`.  I'm assuming `int **event_flags`, but would like to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you shouldn't cast the return of `realloc`.

Then if I suppose that the type of that variable is `int*`

```
*event_flags[flag] = i;
```

There is one `*` too much no?

**Edit:** After your remark on leaving out the cast.

So if your `event_flags` is effectively `int**`, you are really on the wrong track. Seeing your use, I would guess you simply want an array of `int` instead. If you do that and then

```
event_flags[flag] = i;
```

without `*` everywhere, your problem should go away.

If you really need that indirection, you'd have to allocate not only the array `event_flags` but also all the individual arrays these pointers are pointing to, with something like

```
for (size_t j = startvalue; j < something; ++j)
   event_flags[j] = malloc(whatever);
```

Comment: hmmm.. not exactly sure what you mean? Should I just get rid of the cast altogether?

Comment: Yes. Casts in C almost always indicate incorrect code. That is, if your code doesn't compile or gives warnings without casts, you're probably doing something wrong. If it works without the cast, remove the cast so it doesn't suggest to people reading the code that you're performing an ugly hack.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the cast, but then get 'invalid conversion from void* to int**'. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a problem with the precedence of the `*` operator versus the `[]` operator. That is `*event_flags[flag]` and `(*event_flags)[flag]` do not reference the same memory location. The first one correspond to `**(event_flags + flag)` (probably not accessible), while the second one correspond to `*((*event_flags) + flag)` (what you want).

So, you should rewrite your code to:

```
int** event_flags;
// ...
*event_flags = realloc(*event_flags, sizeof(int) * (flag + 1));
(*event_flags)[flag] = i;
```